# 5 sigma result proof for particle discovery

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

Source: Carrolls : "Particle at The End of The Universe" P. 177

[image]

I am just checking my understanding of Carroll's point about "a 5 sigma result being the gold standard" of experimental proof.  Carroll uses the example of flipping a coin 100 times and the expected deviations resulting from that to give an analogy regarding the proof involved in finding the Higgs Boson.

My question is: is my assumption, that because of the probabilistic nature of particle interactions, to get a binomial curve as in the picture above, is what you would expect to find for a "natural" event. It therefore supports the discovery of any new particle, not just Higgs related particles or decay products?

By way of constrast, if we had obtained, for example  a dirac delta distribution, basically just a vertical straight line in the limit, would probably have been viewed as an artifact. Apologies for any loose terminology here.

Hopefully my question is clearly put, I would be happy to clarify further if required.

Comment: Do you know the [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)? Also, it would be preferable if this was a question which doesn't have as a potential answer simply *"Yes, that's right"*.

Comment: CLT is new to me, but I will look it up.  I self study completely, and I have no one else to ask. My own wrong assumptions have wasted a lot of my time and I am trying to avoid this here. 
I completely take your point about _yes, that's right_ questions and if I was convinced I was correct, I would not, I can assure you, be wasting anybody's time (including my own) asking this question.

Comment: I thought this site was ideal for self study types seeking confirmation. Furthermore, I have found more useful material in some of the answers that I, on my own, would have thought of. For example, the central limit theorm that you mentioned.Thanks and regards

Comment: With regards to centering images, [see this Meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6446/centering-a-picture).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the accuracy of the experimental measurements is smaller than the width of the gaussian  then the shape describes the probability distribution one should get for any decay in particle physics. If the experimental accuracy is larger than the width of the decay then one gets a gaussian from the randomness of the experimental error .

Example J/psi in fermilab

[image: jpsifermi]

The true width of the J/psi is of order of keV

The Higgs plot,  where the theoretical width is expected to be of the order of MeV,  has errors of order of  GeV, which is the experimental error width.

> [The Standard prediction](http://home.web.cern.ch/about/updates/2014/03/cms-presents-new-boundary-higgs-width)
>   For a Higgs mass of ~125 GeV, the Standard Model predicts a Higgs width of ~4 MeV. Quite a low width, especially when compared to its compatriots, the W and Z bosons (with ~2 GeV and ~ 2.5 GeV widths, respectively). Before this new result, the best limit on Higgs width had it under 3.4 GeV, based on direct measurements.

..............

> In 2012, theorists demonstrated that, with fewer assumptions and using events with pairs of Z particles, the high invariant mass tail can be used to constrain the Higgs width. Using this technique, the CMS collaboration was able to produce the impressive new result.

Even if  the J/psi ( or the Higgs) were a delta function, still the plot would be the same due to the limits of the experiments.

In other words in particle physics at high energies the errors involved in the measurements will give gaussian distributions due to the randomness of the experimental errors.There is a lot more work involved in measuring the real width coming from the quantum mechanical nature of the decay.

In low energy resonances in particle physics the [Breit Wigner distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Breit%E2%80%93Wigner_distribution) is expected to be fitted to the data, and has been used extensively where the errors are smaller than the real width of the resonance. This is a probability based distribution coming from quantum mechanical calculations.

Now to address the 5 sigma part:

Let us take the discovery of the HIggs for Higgs to gamma gamma

[image: higgsgammagamma]

> [Combined diphoton mass spectrum](http://cms.web.cern.ch/news/cms-closes-major-chapter-higgs-measurements) illustrating the significance of the observed excess, where events are weighted by the expected signal-to-background ratio. The corresponding background-subtracted distribution is shown in the lower panel.

Each experimental  bin in the plot has a statistical error given by the square root of the number of hits for that bin. The background for that bin is at the level of the dashed line under the curve. The background is calculated by using the theory of the standard model in a generator in a monte carlo program that has all the detector errors and behavior incorporated. A large number of monte carlo events are generated to create the solid-dashed curve. The significance is estimated by the difference in the number of events from the dashed line to the curve.

The sum of the events over the background (dashed) curve  has to be equal or  larger than five sigma for the particle physics community to consider it gold plated.

When I was a student more than fifty years ago, four sigma was considered a good solid discovery. Until it was discovered that other factors enter the statistical error, like the look [elsewhere effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-elsewhere_effect), that could give a false security of a gold plated discovery. I was in an experiment where we found a four sigma pimu resonance with four sigma on the curve statistically, which  was not confirmed by any other experiment. This we discovered was due to the great number of cuts done in order to reach the plot that contained the four sigma signal. So even though the signal is still there, someplace in the archives, it is not a secure discovery. The goal posts were moved to five sigma.

The possibility of unknown factors entering an analysis of experimental data is also the reason why there are two similar experiments in the LHC, looking at the same physics with different analysis, instruments, people. Overlooked systematic errors are always a danger in the most carefully done analysis.

Comment: Hi Anna, thanks very much for that, I have no experience of experimental procedures but I will read your answer carefully (and also the central limit theorem). I had not even thought of the experimental errors.  That's the problems with some pop sci books, they just lack the space to deal with important details.   much obliged

Comment: I just got confused, is this 5.th cumulant of the normal distribution? If so, why should be more than 5 to be a proof?

Comment: @Major_Tom It should not be less than five. Think of the whole signal in one bin. the square root of the number is the error to the number.The normal distribution is the   probability distribution for the statistical variations of that one bin. The statistical error on each bin is described by a normal distribution  (turtles all the way down)

Comment: Some pedantry. Your definition of 5-sigma significance sounds to me like it is true only *if* you knew exactly what energy you are looking for. e.g. if I had 1000 independent energy channels, approximately 3 will be >3 sigma above the mean *by chance*. There is still a 1 in 200 chance I would see a 5-sigma blip at random. This is not what 5 sigma means in the context of the Higgs. Secondly - the square root is not really the error bar unless you have a lot of counts per bin. The distribution is the Poisson distribution, is asymmetric and only approximates to a normal distribution.

Comment: @RobJeffries . There are a lot of events in the plots. Poisson is not useful in particle physics currently. Please read my comment to Major above. The whole signal is treated as  one bin  and the probability of 5 sigma over the background event number is 0.000027% probability. In particle physics we know the background curves(see plot above) from monte carlo calculations and look for the new and unexpected as statistical deviations from the background, bin by bin.

Comment: @RobJeffries  have a look at this brazil plot when differences from calculated background were searched to find a signal for a possible Higgs. http://www.atlas.ch/news/images/stories/3-plot.jpg  the caption can be found http://www.atlas.ch/news/2012/latest-results-from-higgs-search.html

Comment: You've edited, but still not indicated that the significance (which is a ratio of two numbers) is the integrated counts above background *in a narrow window* divided by the noise in the expected background over the same window? The italicised bit is important and is why a "3 sigma" detection would not be taken seriously, even though it is a 99.7% confidence result in common parlance.

Comment: In the case of the Higgs the noise in the background is insignificant due to the large number of monte carlo events. The significance is the number of sigma ( square root of n  of the real events) from the background considered constant. It is probably a semantic miss-atribution, as in particle physics we  call the sigmas "significance" implying  the probability value. A bin has N events, the backround is G events, N-G is the signal. The square root(N)/N gives the error, and (N-G)/error is what we call two or three or five sigma significance.

Comment: Noise in the signal (due *mainly* to the noise in the background events actually) is sqrt(N) if G is known/predicted exactly. sqrt(N)/N is a fractional error and not relevant. The S/N is (N-G)/sqrt(N); we agree. Obviously, sqrt(N) increases with the width of the energy range you integrate across, whilst N-G will be roughly constant once above the total width due to the energy resolution (~5 GeV). i.e. You have to tune the detection window to optimise the S/N. This is why "5 sigma" does not in this case mean 0.000027% probability of finding such a peak *anywhere* in the spectrum.

Comment: @RobJeffries Right, not "anywhere". It is a measure of the the reproducibility of the result at the same energy  by another experiment.

Answer (score 1):

The curve you show is *not* a Gaussian. It is a [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with $n=100$ and $p=0.5$ (if it is an unweighted coin). This arises from processes where there are two outcomes. It approximates a Gaussian/Normal distribution when $n$ is large.

This distribution has little to do with particle detection other than perhaps as a means of explaining what is meant by 5-sigma.

In a particle detection experiment you generally expect the detection peak to have a Gaussian with a width equal to the energy resolution of the detector. This is because the intrinsic energy of the particle (depending on its lifetime) will usually be much narrower than the instrumental resolution. However, I do not think that is what you are asking about.

Usually the number of counts detected in a random decay process follows the [*Poisson* distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution). This also *approximates* to a normal distribution in the case where a large number of counts are expected.

The detection of a blip/peak amounts to rejecting the null hypothesis that the peak could have been caused by random chance given a number of expected background events. A 5 sigma detection (should) mean that the excessive number of counts detected would be expected in no more than 1 in about 3.5 million independent randomised trials of the exxperiment, given the level of background expected. However, in the case of detecting a particle of *unknown energy*, life is more complicated. If the peak is allowed to occur at *any* energy, then essentially each independent energy resolution element of your instrument must be included as a random trial. i.e. If there are 20 energy resolution elements (and I am looking at the Higgs plot in AnnaV's answer) then that 1 in 3.5 million reduces to 1 in 175 thousand, because the peak could occur in any one of 20 independent energies. I believe this is what is referred to by AnnaV as the "[look elsewhere effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Look-elsewhere_effect)". See also [this](http://cms.web.cern.ch/news/should-you-get-excited-your-data-let-look-elsewhere-effect-decide) from the CMD website or [page 4 of this](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/9661/1/Higgs_and_Look_Elsewhere_Effect.pdf), which applies the look elsewhere effect to this very Higgs problem and concludes that it is hard to pin down what the look elsewhere factor should be.

A further complication is that the background level *may not* be known exactly and this has to be factored in.

A bottom line would be - if someone says they have a 5-sigma detection, check the small print for what *exactly* they mean by that.

Comment: Hi Rob, you are spot on, that is EXACTLY what Carroll used as an analogy in his book. I screwed up on the Gaussian, as he never mentioned it. I don't (yet at least, if ever) have the background for this. I was not originally even thinking experimentally, just trying to very crudely compare probabilities of various energy levels giving the binomial curve, implying a real particle, as opposed to a spike, implying an artifact, if that makes any sense. Bottom line today for me, I need to read more **before** firing off half baked out questions, a lesson I HAVE learned, believe me regards